# Neither IPN or PDT is working with sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to get notification that a payment has been made so that I can mark an order as "paid" in my database. I set up the sandbox and enabled PDT in my profile but when I place a test order, I don't get any requests to that URL. I tried IPN as well and it's the same. There are no errors or anything. No requests are coming in at all. I don't see anything in my server logs indicating that an attempt was made (Nothing in access_log or error_log).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have a look in the sandbox log. It shows when they sent anything.

Comment: Hmm. I don't see the logs anywhere. Where do I find this? In the sandbox paypal account or in the developer account? I don't see it at either of these.

Comment: There's nothing in the logs. Strange.

Comment: What logs are you looking at?  Are you looking at the IPN History in the sandbox seller account where IPN is configured?  Are you sure you're submitting payments to the same account that you configured IPN with?  I've got all sorts of IPN's hitting my server from the sandbox, so it seems to be working fine from what I can see.

Comment: I am so stupid. I just realized it was using the old account from the wordpress cache plugin. It's working fine now (IPN). There is still no PDT but I think I can live without that.